# When I create RecurringPaymentsProfile and set initialAmount but can't receive IPN message

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-ipn

I use [merchant-sdk-java](https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-java).
when step by setExpressCheckout, I set the NotifyURL. 
After I create RecurringPaymentsProfile and set initialAmount like:

```
ActivationDetailsType activationDetails = new ActivationDetailsType(
            new BasicAmountType(CurrencyCodeType.fromValue(ecParam.currencyCode), ecParam.currency));
    activationDetails.setFailedInitialAmountAction(FailedPaymentActionType.CONTINUEONFAILURE);
    scheduleDetails.setActivationDetails(activationDetails);
```

But I didn't receive IPN message, who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

The NotifyURL use for DoEC, If I use RecurringPaymentsProfile , must use global IPN url.